# How to pre-process ordinal feature where feature values are range of numbers and rank or encode them accordingly

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data, feature-engineering

I have the following feature column in my dataset:

```
+-----------+
|   size    |
+-----------+
| 10-90     |
| <10       |
| 100-200   |
| 10-90     |
| 500-800   |
| 10000+    |
| <10       |
| 1000-4999 |
+-----------+
```

I am a novice in machine learning, and am finding it difficult to deal with such a feature set.

When I do:

```
import pandas as pd

y = pd.Categorical(train['size'],ordered=True)
```

The output of y is :

```
[10-90, <10, 100-200, 10-90, 500-800, 10000+, <10, 1000-4999]
Categories (6, object): [10-90 < 100-200 < 1000-4999 < 10000+ < 500-800 < <10]
```

which is wrong, since <10 should get the lowest rank, and also 500-800 gets a wrong rank.
According to this feature set >10000 or 10000+ should have gotten the highest rank.

I need to rank or encode this data accordingly, such that if my test data gets the value 5, or <5 it should get the same rank or encoding as <10, since that's the nearest one.

Is there any method/package in python or R that can help me achieve this?
Kindly help.

Comment: I am not `r` coder, but how working `y = factor(train$size, levels = c('<10', '10-90' , '100-200','500-800', '1000-4999', '10000+'))` ?

Answer (score 3):

**Pandas** solution is also specify `categories` is expected order:

```
cats= ['<10', '10-90' , '100-200','500-800', '1000-4999', '10000+']
y = pd.Categorical(train['size'],ordered=True, categories=cats)
print (y)
[10-90, <10, 100-200, 10-90, 500-800, 10000+, <10, 1000-4999]
Categories (6, object): [<10 < 10-90 < 100-200 < 500-800 < 1000-4999 < 10000+]
```

Comment: x = np.unique(train_data['size'])
print(x)
array(['10-90', '100-200', '1000-4999', '10000+', '500-800', '<10'],
      dtype=object)
y = pd.Categorical(train_data['size'],ordered=True,categories=x)
print(y)
[10-90, <10, 100-200, 10-90, 500-800, 10000+, <10, 1000-4999]
Categories (6, object): [10-90 < 100-200 < 1000-4999 < 10000+ < 500-800 < <10]

So, this is still not giving me the correct arrangement.
Also, how will I use the categorical arrangement to give rank to the values in the feature column?
And how to deal with a new value in test data?

Comment: Your code is wrong, because need specify catagories manually, because `print (x)` create wrong order, because sorting lexicographically, like strings.

Comment: And for rank use `print (y.codes)` - [`codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.codes.html)

Comment: There are many levels in my data. So I want to avoid manual categorization. I understand if that's the only way. Is there a way to map an unseen data, say, <5 to the same rank as less <10?  or 20000 to the same rank as 10000+?

Comment: @rjdj - Hard question, theoretically yes. Give me some time.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

**R** solution:

```
cats = c('<10', '10-90' , '100-200','500-800', '1000-4999', '10000+')

 factor(train$size,levels = cats,ordered = TRUE)
[1] 10-90     <10       100-200   10-90     500-800   10000+    <10       1000-4999
Levels: <10 < 10-90 < 100-200 < 500-800 < 1000-4999 < 10000+
```

or

```
ordered(train[['size']], levels=cats)
[1] 10-90     <10       100-200   10-90     500-800   10000+    <10       1000-4999
Levels: <10 < 10-90 < 100-200 < 500-800 < 1000-4999 < 10000+
```

Whether you take python or R, one thing you need to know is that you need to put the categories in the order you would like. Can only be done Manually..